# Creating a handler for link popup inside Quill Editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I want to create a link using popup form which takes form data(Link title and Link url) and then add this link to the editor.

Something like Reddit editor [image]

My starter code which does not work as I wanted it to be

```
class LinkBlot extends Inline {
    static create(url, title) {
      let node = super.create();
      // Sanitize url value if desired
      node.setAttribute('href', url);
      // Okay to set other non-format related attributes
      // These are invisible to Parchment so must be static
      node.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      node.setAttribute('title', title);
      return node;
    }

    static formats(node) {
      // We will only be called with a node already
      // determined to be a Link blot, so we do
      // not need to check ourselves
      return node.getAttribute('href') || true;
    }
    format(name, value) {
        if (name === 'link' && value) {
            this.domNode.setAttribute('href', value);
        } else {
            super.format(name, value);
        }
    }

    formats() {
        let formats = super.formats();
        formats['link'] = LinkBlot.formats(this.domNode);
        return formats;
    }
}
LinkBlot.blotName = 'link';
LinkBlot.tagName = 'a';
Quill.register(LinkBlot);
document.querySelector('#link-insert-btn').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkText = document.getElementById('link-text').value;
    var linkURL = document.getElementById('link-url').value;
    quill.format('link', linkURL, linkText);
});
```

Some help would be appreciated.